# How do you handle library dependencies during deployment using PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dependency-management

this is a question on PHP mainly. I was wondering: How do you make sure that all necessary libaries are packaged with your application when you do a deployment to (production) servers?

A more concrete example: I have an app running on Zend Framework and each time I roll the application to a server the deployment process creates a fresh "installation" on that system. Therefore, I need to bundle Zend Framework together with my application and then copy the files to the right places together (it is done automatically). Currently, I am using a svn:externals definition to get the files out of Zend's SVN system during deployment, however, I don't want to rely on that SVN and I also don't want to put traffic on external SVNs with each deployment.

In the Java world, I am used to Maven which handles such stuff using central artifact repositries. I know that there is a Maven4PHP version, however, I am more looking for a PHP-based solution. Additionally, I don't believe that PEAR is a good way to go as it doesn't really fulfill my requirement of bundling the applicaiton (incl. libs) into a single deployable.

Is there some tool available already that I am not aware? Or do you have any great technique that I should know?

Thanks much for your help!

Michael

Answer (score 3):

There's a build system called [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/) which is written in PHP and based on Apache Ant.

I personally can very well live with externals.

Comment: Yeah, I know Phing! Is there an out-of-the-box task to resolve dependencies? Or is it about writing my own task? Thanks!

Comment: @Michael I handle dependencies with phing with a simpler approach.  It may not be as robust as a dependency task probably should be, but I have a set of phing helpers that are simple build scripts designed for inclusion with the import task, in my project helper it defines a resolve-deps task that is a foreach that runs a phing task to an external build script with properties assigned that define the dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [vendor branching](http://www.linxit.de/svnbook/en/1.1/ch07s05.html) would solve the problem from your example quite straightforward, but if you also don't like large repositories I'd recommended to keep watching on the modern toys like [composer](https://github.com/composer/composer) and [what it solve](http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/composer_solves_the_php_code-sharing_problem/)(and maybe [phark](https://github.com/lox/phark), I never heard before :) )

Comment: +1 for mentioning composer, this is an old question I reckon, however by now absolute majority of PHP projects use Composer for dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't production ready yet but you might want to keep an eye on the [Phark](https://github.com/lox/phark) project. It is a port of [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to PHP.

While looking through the [Simplify your external dependency management](http://www.slideshare.net/shochdoerfer/simplify-your-external-dependency-management-dpc11) slides I came across a tool called pantr which can be used as a PEAR installer. [pantr as PEAR installer](https://github.com/pago/pantr/wiki/pantr-as-PEAR-installer) which allows you to specify your dependencies in a project specific file.

The article [Version Control != Dependency Management](http://www.tricode.nl/version-control-dependency-management/) has some information about using the new PEAR installer called [Pyrus](http://pear2.php.net/)